# Android - OkHTTP requests

Tags: android, web-services, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I am using HttpUrlConnection for doing requests to my mysql db using webservices. With HttpUrlConnection I can execute all my requests in background so the main thread don't get overloaded and start skipping frames.

With okHttp how does this is achieved? How do I make a request with it and print a response using JSON? Is it better than httpUrlConnection?

P.S I do not know anything about okHttp, I will be grateful if you are explicit with your examples.

Answer (score 2):

> With okHttp how does this is achieved?

Typically, you let it handle the background thread for you, using `enqueue()` for asynchronous operation:

```
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        // handle the error
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
          // use the result
      }
    });
  }
```

(sightly simplified from [the OkHttp docs](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get))

Or, if you already have a background thread, you can use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()` for synchronous operation.

You might wish to review the other examples on [the OkHttp recipes page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes), plus [the OkHttp Web page](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), plus [the OkHttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki), to get a better sense of how it compares with what you are used to.

Comment: Consider using retrofit with okhttp to make the whole thing even easier.